# jQuery/Javascript equivalent of CSS Counter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to implement a counter which directly changes the text of a tag using jQuery/Javascript? For example if I had 2  tags:

```
<a>hello</a>
<a>bye</a>
```

After running the jQuery/JS function, this is what would happen:

```
<a>[1]hello</a>
<a>[2]bye</a>
```

I can't use a CSS counter as I need the script to directly edit the HTML.

Comment: For each one of the elements, set the text, then increment the number.

Comment: so select the elements, loop, and add the text??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `.html(function)`

```js
$("a").html(function(index, html) {
  return "[" + (index + 1) + "]" + html;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<a>hello</a>
<a>bye</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could loop through all the anchors and add the index to the content using `.prepend()` :

```
$("a").each(function(index,value) {
    $(this).prepend("["+(index++)+"] ");
})
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$("a").each(function(index,value) {
   $(this).prepend("["+(index++)+"] ");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<a>hello</a>
<a>bye</a>
```

Comment: Why is `.each()` necessary? `.html()` iterates all elements of jQuery object.

Comment: This is another solution to the OP question :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this code,

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<a>hello</a>
<a>bye</a>

<script>
$("a").html(function(index, data) {
  return "[" + (index + 1) + "]" + data;
})
</script>
```

Comment: How is `javascript` at Answer different from `javascript` at http://stackoverflow.com/a/41384631/?

Comment: @user7354735 no need for duplicate answers please.

Comment: This not a duplicate answer, I am just indicating the Place which is suitable to put the jQuery Function

Comment: Do not fight with me man, It is a simple and common script, can't write in a multiple way

Comment: And how changing `html` to `data` supposed to make difference?

Comment: I just edited like that to change my answer from your view, I can't do anything rather than this update in my mind, otherwise i want to delete my answer.
Check others answer also, All are same in the common manner

Comment: @user7354735 _"Check others answer also, All are same in the common manner"_ Is Answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/41384839 also "same in the common manner" as the "other answers" at http://stackoverflow.com/q/41384702 ?

Answer (score 1):

With pure JS, you can use create a *text node* and insert it as the *first child node* to get the *counters* - see a demo below:

```js
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("a"), function(e, i) {
  e.insertBefore(document.createTextNode(`[${i+1}]`), e.childNodes[0]);
});
```

```html
<a>hello</a>
<a>bye</a>
```